# GSL statistics, what is stride?

Tags: c++, c, statistics, gsl, standard-deviation

I would like to use GSL (Gnu Scientific Lib) to calculate the standard deviation of an array.
http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Mean-and-standard-deviation-and-variance.html

In the manual, the function prototype is
gsl_stats_sd (const double data[], size_t stride, size_t n)

However, I don't quite understand what the "stride" is here. Would somebody know what it is?

Comment: http://www.mail-archive.com/help-gsl@gnu.org/msg02822.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A *stride* is the separation in the array between two consecutive elements. If you have an array of `double`s as the argument, then the *stride* would be 1.

The idea is that you can handle multiple data within a single array, and operate on different *subcomponents* of the array.

Comment: Thanks, K-ballo! It makes sense now! I wish to contribute to the manual to make it more clear...

Comment: It should be clarified that the stride is measured in multiples of sizeof(double) from the beginning of one element to the next.  Internally, GSL reads array elements like this: `data[i * stride]`

Comment: stride is measured in multiple of sizeof(double)? WTF, why not just take the offset of the variable in the struct??